# dynamic in C# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0

In PowerShell I can set a variable to a string and then use it on a hash table lookup:

```
$h = @{a=1}
$p = "a"

$h.$p
```

How can this be done in C# 4.0 with method calls? The following fails because target is not resolved to 'MethodToCall'.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string target = "MethodToCall";
        dynamic d = new test();
        d.target();
    }
}

class test
{
    public void MethodToCall()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what "dynamic" lets you do.  C# is different from PowerShell here.

Comment: Remember that C# is not a scripting language.

Comment: Yes, I know. I realize I am trying to make it one :)

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic is not the solution. You migth need to use reflection.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string target = "MethodToCall";
    var d = new test();
    typeof(test).InvokeMember(target, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, d, null);
}
```